# Magento Sitemap Causing Error

Tags: php, css, magento, magento-1.7, block

All the sudden in the admin side when I go to submit sitemap it shows up a white screen. Here's what my error logs show.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /home/investor/public_html/yourvaporizers.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/SitemapController.php on line 99
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in /home/investor/public_html/yourvaporizers.com/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sitemap_Grid.php on line 47
```

Not a coder so have no clue how to fix this.

UPDATE - I should of added the whole error code.

```
Stack trace:
0 /home/investor/public_html/yourvaporizers.com/includes/src/__default.php(63823): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
1      /home/investor/public_html/yourvaporizers.com/includes/src/Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql.php    (110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
2 /home/investor/public_html/yourvaporizers.com/includes/src/__default.php(63411): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
3 /home/investor/public_html/yourvaporizers.com/includes/src/__default.php(52806): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
4 /home/investor/public_html/yourvaporizers.com/includes/src/__default.php(53842): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `mg_core...', Array)
5 /home/investor/public_html/yourvaporizers.com/includes/src/__default.php(54687): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `mg_core...', Array)
6 /home/investor/p in /home/investor/public_html/yourvaporizers.com/includes/src/__default.php on line 63829
[07-Apr-2014 07:51:25 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in     /home/investor/public_html/yourvaporizers.com/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sitemap_Grid.php on line 47
[07-Apr-2014 07:51:28 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /home/investor/public_html/yourvaporizers.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/SitemapController.php on line 99
[07-Apr-2014 07:51:32 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in /home/investor/public_html/yourvaporizers.com/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sitemap_Grid.php on line 47
[07-Apr-2014 08:07:18 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in /home/investor/public_html/yourvaporizers.com/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sitemap_Grid.php on line 47
[07-Apr-2014 10:03:37 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap' not found in /home/investor/public_html/yourvaporizers.com/app/code/community/Creare/CreareSeoCore/Model/Sitemap/Sitemap.php on line 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's line 99 of that file

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/SitemapController.php
$this->_title($model->getId() ? $model->getSitemapFilename() : $this->__('New Sitemap'));
```

So, it looks like Magento is trying to call `getId` on the `$model` variable, but `$model` is not an object. If we look to where `$model` was assigned/defined, in a stock system, we see

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/SitemapController.php
$model = Mage::getModel('sitemap/sitemap');
```

So, there's two possible reasons for your error.  First, you, or someone else, installed an extension into your Magento system and it did something (class rewrite, behavior change) that caused a recoverable error when attempting to instantiate the `sitemap/sitemap` model. This results in `$model` being `false`, and leads to your error.

The second is someone has change this file or the site map model file (either in `core` or one of the code pools `community`, `local`) and did something that leads to `$model` being undefined.

Debugging steps would include diffing against a freshly downloaded copy, and disabling any extensions related to the site map functionality (or installed recently).  As for

> Not a coder so have no clue how to fix this.

the better question might be

> Why is a non-coder working with a system that, for years, has proven you need to be a coder (or willing to learn) to work with.

Comment: I had a new extension I've installed but I really want to keep it since it is important. Are there any solutions of what I should do? If I upload a clean copy of those files, won't the extension screw with it again? I can read code and edit code but some thing I don't understand. I'm learning coding fyi and I still don't believe you need coding experience to use Magento, I've been using it fine for over 2 years. Coding just helps, you just have to have good sense, good research skills to make it work if your not a coder.

Comment: Step 1 is figuring out what the problem is (extension, hacked file, etc).  Step 2 is addressing the problem (if possible).